# How to remove a single registry VALUE at uninstall of an MSI?

Tags: windows-installer, registry, uninstallation

There is a particular registry value that my application sometimes creates during execution, i.e. NOT at installation. This value is within a registry key that I don't want to delete; I just want to delete the value that I created. Because it's not created at install it's not automatically deleted at uninstall by windows installer. What can I do in the MSI to delete this value if it exists?

The [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371168%28VS.85%29.aspx) table doesn't seem to have this option. Does that mean I have to write a custom action? If so, anyone have any examples?

I'm using Wise Windows Installer Edition to create the MSI.

Also posted [here](https://www-secure.symantec.com/connect/forums/how-remove-single-registry-value-uninstall-msi).

Comment: It's awfull that MSI didn't provide standard technology for removing RegistryValue. How for example we should remove HKCU/Windows/Current/Version/Run/My Program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to do a custom action.

I ended up implementing this with a custom action placed after the WriteRegistryValues within Deferred section.

The .vbs to delete the key is like this:

```
const HKLM = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions"
strValueName = "myext@myco.com"
oReg.DeleteValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you will need a custom action.

Comment: Unfortunately that's for removing registry entries when components are _installed_ not uninstalled.

Comment: You are correct. I was thinking along the lines of the RemoveFile table that has an attribute called msidbRemoveFileInstallModeOnRemove.  I don't know what this registry value is but would it be ok to leave it on uninstall but make sure it gets removed on the next install?   From the applications runtime perspective I think the result would be the same.   Or is this registry value manipulating something at the OS level and not the application itself?  I know to write a new value during uninstall I needed a custom action.

Comment: The value is registering my software as an extension with Firefox, so nope, would be bad to leave it there as it affects other software. A custom action it will be then!